# How do I prove the implication "p": (3 does not divide n) --> 'q" (3 divides n^2 + 2) specifically using contrapositive.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

I can do this with a direct proof and but I cannot figure out how to do it with contrapositive.

My steps so far have been:

Proof by contraposition:

Assuming $3$ doesn't divide $n^2 + 2$, we must prove that $3$ does not divide n is false, or $3$ divides n is true.

i.e. $n^2 + 2$ exists in $\{3k + 1, 3k + 2\}$ where $k$ exists in all integers.

then $n^2$ exists in $\{3k - 1, 3k\}$.

$n^2 = 3k - 1$ where $n$ and $k$ are both integers.

Assume that there exists a $k$ for which $3k - 1$ is a perfect square,

i.e. $3k - 1 = n^2$

(End of the proof I have so far)

How do I proceed from here? How do I prove that 3k - 1 can never be a perfect square and then how do I show that if $n^2 = 3k$ from "then $n^2$ exists in $\{3k - 1, 3k\}$.", 
then if $n$ is an integer then $\sqrt(3k)$ is divisible by $3$ and that p is false if q is false?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  If $n=3m$ then $3$ divides $n^2=9m^2$.  If $n=3m\pm1$ then $3$ divides $n^2-1=9m^2\pm6m.$  So in no case does $3$ divide $n^2+1$ (i.e., $3k-1\ne n^2$)

Answer (score 1):

Let $n = 3j + i$ where $i = 0, 1, $or $-1$

$n^2 = 9j^2 + 6ji + i^2= 3(3j^2 + 2ji) + i^2= 3M + i^2$ where $M = (3j^2 + 2ji)$ and $i^2 = 0$ or $1$ but $i^2 \ne -1$.

Can you finish?

> So $n^2 \ne 3k -1$ for any $k$.  So $n^2 = 3k$ is the only option.

.

> But $n^2 = 3M + i^2$ so $i^2 = 0$ and $i = 0$.

.

> So $n = 3j$.

Comment: if $i = 0$ then that makes n divisible by 3. Shouldn't it only be i = +- 1?

Comment: "If $i = 0$ that makes $n$ divisible by $3$."  .... Well, .... yeah? ... That's what we *want*!  Why would we try to avoid that?  So if $i^2 = 1$ is impossible then $i^2 = 0$ and $i=0$ is the only thing *left*.  So we get $i=0$ and $n$ is divisible by $3$.  Which is what we were trying to prove!  So we are done.  Let's break out the champagne and go home.